# Jupyter notebook to beamer

Tags: beamer, python

There are plenty of solutions to transform a RStudio script to Beamer. However, there are not solutions to transform a Jupyter notebook of Python to Beamer... Is there any automatic way to insert every chunk of the notebook in a different slide of a Beamer? It will be merged with another .tex beamer.

Comment: Welcome! A jupyter notebook is a "one flow"-type of document, so I think that an automatic passage to `beamer` will be quite difficult. But you can generate a LaTeX document; after that, splitting into frames should not be so difficult.

Comment: I think this is a nice idea in general, and technically it should be feasible because Notebooks are very structured. However, a practical problem is that beamer slides, by design, don't fit a lot of information. Therefore the slides will often overflow, both for the code blocks and for the text blocks. I teach a Python course with beamer slides and I often need to adjust code to make it fit on the slide (it probably doesn't help that I still use an aspect ratio of 4:3).

Answer (score 2):

I concur with the Rmano's answer. I also tried that and I could get my beamer slides after making only few changes to the Jupyter-generated Tex file. I will elaborate so that others may follow.

1. Generate tex file using Jupyter as `File-> Download as-> Tex file.`
2. Make necessary changes to the tex file, viz.

   a. change the document type
   `\documentclass[10pt]{article}`   to `\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}`.

   b. Comment out the line containing `\usepackage{titling}`.

   c. change the geometry setting to

   ```
    \geometry{verbose,tmargin=0in,bmargin=0in,lmargin=.5in,rmargin=.5in}
   ```
3. Wrap the Jupyter generated tex code in a frame as follows.

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,fragile]
<here comes the code>
\end{frame}
```

It may be separated into chunks as per requirement.

Here is the screenshot
[image]

**Caveat**: I also tried with the text cells containing text and math equations. This method seems to work with plain text cells only.

Comment: Interesting. Could you show a screenshot of how the result looks? Did you try with a code-only notebook, or did it also have text cells in between with headers and formatting?

Comment: @Marijn following your cue I tested and updated the answer. Unfortunately, the cells containing the equations are not properly formatted.